# Laravel DB::transaction() not recognized in controller

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, laravel-5.6

I want to use transactions in my controller, but when I typed in DB::transaction(), its not recognized by it, also the autocomplete doesn't show transaction() as a function inside DB. I'm new to laravel, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` above the class declaration?
This is used to import the DB facade.

Comment: Yes I've done that as well.

Comment: What editor do you use? I am trying it with PHPStorm, also have the alias in the `app/config.php` `'DB'           => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,` so even just using `use DB;` the autocomplete works for transaction. You can open the Facade and within you will see in the comment all the functions that are available on the class.
If the class is not available than you might have missed to install the packages using `composer install`.

Comment: I'm also using phpstorm. And have that alias as well.

Comment: Have you tried to open the facade, can you at all open it? I mean the DB facade.

Comment: I did. I dont see transaction in it.

Comment: So as it seems the function works and doesn't produce an error, its the IDE that doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I thought you had other issue rather then just the IDE not autocompleting the functions. Try installing https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin and see if it helps

Comment: I believed so it was causing a problem, then i decided to run the code and it worked just fine. I'll try installing that.

Answer (score 2):

Try using like this..

\DB::transaction();